# SSL Mixed Content WordPress Site. TRIED EVERYTHING

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https, mixed-content

I am trying to fix mixed content warning from an SSL certificate install. I have tried multiple things such as adding redirects to the .htaccess. Deleting the images and reuploading them and just deleting the images all together but no luck. Can anyone help me get to the bottom of how to fix the mixed content so I can get the green padlock?

The mixed content warnings are as followed:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.laser-scanning.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.laser-scanning.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/black-arrow-down.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.laser-scanning.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.laser-scanning.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/eoa-team.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

[image: Console output]

https://www.laser-scanning.co.uk/

Comment: Please don't post images without corresponding text. In this case, please copy and paste the Warnings into your question.

Comment: @RussJ this has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a plugin to search and replace all HTTP request to HTTPS. I used to configure following [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) which will do the trick. Better, take a backup of existing database and do the changes.

Also, update URL in [CSS file](https://www.laser-scanning.co.uk/wp-content/themes/stockholm/css/custom_css.css?ver=1573243956) or keep only relative URLs.

[image]

Comment: I tried that plugin with no success. I also tried to search and replace in my SQL and that did not work either.

Comment: @MatthewSmith Do a test by removing browser cache or disable if any cache plugins installed. In general, the mentioned plugin will work perfectly in such situations. Also, go to Settings -> General and click Save Changes button to make sure that all necessary settings are updated.

Comment: @MatthewSmith Try using [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin too. Run as dry run & check whether the table were affected with your searched URL or not. [Screen Shot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sUmJgWl_Lva1g6phnd85O3FmpWERTxIG)

Comment: Neither of these solutions worked, as you can see all tables have been changed. https://ibb.co/gW1gNSv

Comment: @MatthewSmith it seems like you have hard coded entire website URL in [CSS file](https://www.laser-scanning.co.uk/wp-content/themes/stockholm/css/custom_css.css?ver=1573243956). Open the CSS, and search for your domain where you will find calls with HTTP. Always better to use relative URLs to avoid such issues.

Comment: I took over the site, I did not build it. Thank you so much!! Could I ask how you debugged that so If I ever come across the issue again I can solve it.

Comment: @MatthewSmith Using console window in Chrome, I was able to identify that image is being called through CSS file. Review the [screen shot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PkRFKmCqJILqe3R7PGwUY5NhvGly1-m3) which will give you more picture. Please accept the answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewSmith I can see that your website is properly loading with SSL & connection is secured. Hope you can mark my above answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To change all the urls in the database you can use a plugin, my favorite for this is: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/
Never had any old urls in the page after using this.

But it could be, that you have put this images urls in the template php files of your theme. Have you checked the theme files if there are the url inserted? maybe the logo is set in the header.php or something like that.

It could also be there is a plugin to serve the image urls.

This kind of things are not affected if you are changing the data in your database with a plugin. Could be worth a try checking that.

**EDIT:** You asked how you can find out the place where the image url can be set:

If you inspect your website, the console tells you that you have mixed content. On the right side of this message, it also tells you where it is.

In your case, http://www.laser-scanning.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/black-arrow-down.png" is found in videocontrols.js:428:67

So the url is set in the videocontrols.js. Find this file in your theme or inside a plugin. You can also find the place where the js videocontrols is included in your site. That way you know the path of where the videocontrols.js is located.

Your second mixed content is found in mediaelement-and-player.min.js and is http://www.laser-scanning.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/eoa-team.jpg .

So both of your images are loaded inside of javascript files. That is the reason why updating the urls in the database is not working.

Find this two javascript files and edit the url to contain the https.

Hope this will help.

Comment: The plugin **Go Live Update URL** did not work and the site is still showing mixed content on the images screenshotted above. Is there any method you'd advise to locate the URLs in the template files,

Comment: I edited my post. The two images are loaded in javascript files.

Comment: I see your website is now not facing the problem anymore. If the answer solved your problem, please mark my answer as the accepted answer. If you solved the problem with another solution, please post your solution to let others know facing similar problems. Thank you!